# how to declare string value for firebase database child

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want save my data every time if I click on `button`. Every time i click the button, different of the child name will store in database What I can do with the current code.

```
databaseReference.orderByChild("previousLocation")
                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                    .getReference("Location").child();
                  //Database child with value of Lang1

                 myLocation locationDB = new myLocation(lang1, long1);
                            databaseReference.setValue(locationDB);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `child()`, call `push()`. This creates a reference to a new, unique location in your database under `Location`. So:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Location").push();

  myLocation locationDB = new myLocation(lang1, long1);
  databaseReference.setValue(locationDB);
}
```